# Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{3x}\sin{\frac{5x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \;{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm not sure how to evaluate: $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{3x}\sin{\frac{5x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \;\mathrm{d}x\ $$  I assume it's some method of angle addition decomposition to cancel the denominator but I'm just not sure.
Answer is $\frac{38}{15}$

Comment: I'd write the integrand in terms of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Try with $\sin(a)\sin(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b))$...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak how would I simplify $\frac{\cos{\frac{11x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}$ ?

Comment: It can be done with pencil and paper, and addition theorems.

Comment: To @user760219 : Try now with $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a) \cos(b) - \sin(a) \sin(b)$, where you will have $a=5\pi$, $b=\frac{\pi}{2}$...

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\frac{\sin{\frac{5x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}=1+2\cos x+2\cos2x $$

Thus,

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{3x}\sin{\frac{5x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \;{\rm d}x
=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin 3x (1+2\cos x+2\cos2x)dx=\frac{38}{15}
$$

Comment: Sorry but how do you go from the first fraction to the cosines?

Comment: @user760219 Why don't you try to prove it for yourself?  Surely you must have some idea about how to do this via trigonometric identities?

Comment: @user760219 - multiply RHS by $\sin\frac x2$ and use the trig identity for $\sin a\cos b $ for each term

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

From the formula for the sum of sines of arcs in arithmetic progression:
$$\sin x+\sin 2x+\dots+\sin nx=\frac{\sin\cfrac{(n+1)x}2}{\sin\cfrac x2}\,\sin\frac{nx}2, $$
you deduce instantly that the integrand is
$$\sin x+\sin 2x+\dots+\sin 6x.$$